# Telnet for port 80 not working

Tags: telnet

I am doing telnet as

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

It is showing `Trying 216.58.193.164...`.Nothing happens after that. but when I tried

```
telnet www.google.com 443
```

It works well and shows

```
Trying 216.58.193.68...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My all outbound ports are open. Then what can be the reasons for this problem?

Comment: If the message you are getting something like `connection timed out` after a while, your firewall ports are not as open as you might think. If this is a corporate environment, there might be a stateful packet inspection going on and telnet is not allowed in most everywhere I have been, in the past few years.

Answer (score 3):

What error symptoms do you see?  When I issue that command, I see this:

```
% telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 216.58.218.164...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

That is correct behavior. The HTTP client must issue a command at this point in the protocol.  If you type:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: www.google.com
```

And hit "return" twice, you will see HTML sent by www.google.com